# Аннотации Springа

Tags: spring, java

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем разница между `@Autowired`, `@Required` и `@Resource`.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/

Comment: @Nofate а почему сделана такая ассоциация? Ведь в этом вопросе сравниваются аннотации по внедрению зависимостей, а в том - сравнивают аннотации для обозначения компонента/сервиса/репозитория.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@Required` отмечает свойства бина, которые обязательно должны быть установлены.

`@Autowired` используется для автоматического внедрения зависимости. Вы отмечаете им некое свойство в бине и Spring сам создаст экземпляр класса, подходящего для этого свойства.

`@Resource`, в отличие от `@Autowired`, позволяет передать в качестве зависимости конкретный бин по его имени.

Все достаточно неплохо описано в [документации](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s11.html).

---

Пример.

```
class Foo {
  private Bar bar;

  public void setBar(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы Spring сам нашел подходящий класс и передал его экземпляр в `setBar()` проставьте перед методом аннотацию `@Autowired`.

Если вы хотите передать конкретный бин, в качестве параметра `setBar()`, воспользуйтесь аннотацией `@Resource(name="myBarBean")`.

Если свойство `foo` обязательно должно заполняться, добавьте аннотацию `@Required`.