# Аннотации @Autowired и @Resource

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался.

Изучаю сравнение аннотаций `@Autowired` и `@Resource`. Создала класс `Dog` и `Person`, у которого есть `Dog`. Конфигурация через код в классе. Сначала  попробовала внедрить зависимость через `@Autowired` - всё работает. Поменяла на `@Resource` (несколько вариантов) - выдает `NullPointerException`. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

Заранее спасибо.

```
    public interface Pet {
    public void voice ();
}

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

@Component ("dog")
@Scope("singleton")
public class Dog implements Pet {
    public Dog () {
        System.out.println("Dog start");
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init () {
        System.out.println("init start - Dog");
    }
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy () {
        System.out.println("destroy start - Dog ");
    }
    public void voice() {
        System.out.println("gaw");
    }


}

@Component ("person")
public class Person {

    private Pet pet;
    private String name;

    public Pet getPet() {
        return pet;
    }

    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("start setName");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        System.out.println("start setAge");
        this.age = age;
    }


    public Person() {

    }
    @Resource
    @Qualifier( "dog")
    public void setPet ( Pet pet) {
        this.pet = pet;

    }

    public void callYouPet() {
        System.out.println("Hello, Pet");
        pet.voice();
    }



}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan ("org.example")
public class MyConfig {
}


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
        Dog dog = context.getBean("dog", Dog.class);
        Person person = context.getBean("person", Person.class);
        person.callYouPet();
        // Car car = context.getBean(Car.class);
        //car.drive("John");
       // car.drive("Michel");
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33520/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-spring%d0%b0?rq=1)

Comment: Я использовала все возможные комбинации с @Resource, результат один и тот же - .NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.example.Pet.voice()" because "this.pet" is null

Answer (score 0):

В итоге просто поигралась с зависимостями, и всё заработало.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```